# React fontawesome 5 SVG not rerendering

Tags: reactjs, svg, font-awesome

I am using a pro license of Fontawesome 5 with React and I have created a row header component for the header cell in a div table. The cell has Fontawesome generated svgs for the sort icons. I can't get the SVGs to rerender.

Here is my code:

```js
export const row = (value, className, clickHandler) => (
  <div className={`align-self-center text-center ${className ? className : ''}`} onClick={clickHandler}>
    {value}
  </div>
);

export const rowHeader = (value, className, sort, clickHandler) => {
  let iconClass;
  switch (sort) {
    case 'asc':
      iconClass =  'fas fa-sort-up';
      break;
    case 'desc':
      iconClass = 'fas fa-sort-down';
      break;
    default:
      iconClass = 'fal fa-sort';
      break;
  }

  return row(<span>{value} {iconClass} <i className={iconClass + ' float-right'}/></span>, className +  ' clickable', clickHandler);
};
```

I tried creating the `<i .../>` as a separate component and that didn't work. The icons render correctly the first time appropriatelys and the `iconClass` is being changed in my cell. However, the SVG element is not being rerendered.

How do I force the Fontawesome generated SVG icons to rerender when the parent element rerenders?

Comment: As a temporary work around I am using the NPM package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome with @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid. That work with the solid icons but I would love to use the light icons that are included with the pro license. I am using both in the code above.

Comment: Yea, I lied. That only sort of works. The SVG icons are switched the first time but they do not rerender after that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that finally worked. I was able to find the documentation for using my pro license.

```js
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSortDown, faSortUp } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid';
import { faSort } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light';

export const row = (value, className, clickHandler) => (
  <div className={`align-self-center text-center ${className ? className : ''}`} onClick={clickHandler}>
    {value}
  </div>
);

export const rowHeader = (value, className, sort, clickHandler) => {
  return row(<span>{value} {sortIcon(sort)}</span>, className +  ' clickable', clickHandler);
};

export const sortIcon = (sort) => {
  switch (sort) {
    case 'asc':
      return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSortDown} size='lg' className='float-right'/>;
    case 'desc':
      return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSortUp} size='lg' className='float-right'/>;
    default:
      return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSort} size='lg' className='float-right'/>;
  }
};
```

Edit - Clarification:

The problem appeared to be that changing the CSS class names on the rendered SVG elements would not cause React to re-render them. Switching to the React Fontawesome library and updating the FontAwesomeIcon component worked.

Comment: Can you isolate the fix here so we can find it quickly? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

My solution was to add `key={Math.random()}` to the SVG's containing element. Then, when it gets new props, it forces a refresh.

Comment: This one worked for me when the rerendering was not working inside SVG

Comment: Instead of using random one could use ID and state descriptor, like `sort` variable mentioned in the question source, so `key` would be e.g. `price-row-icon-asc`. I think that would look less hacky. ;)

Comment: 2 1/2 half years later this was the solution that helped me the most. As `key` I used a template string containing all properties I want to be reactive. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is because the svg&js flavor of Font Awesome uses a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which will replace all icon elements with `svg` elements.

This means the DOM will be manipulated, which will cause trouble if you're using React to render the DOM. Your icons are not re-rendering, simply because React is no longer able to find them in the DOM because the Font Awesome library has replaced the original element with an `svg` element. This can lead to other problems as well, see this question: [Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' with FontAwesome in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358529/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-with-fontawesome-in-react)

To fix this you can use the `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` library as you already mentioned in your own answer, or, if you're like me and don't like the verbosity (and having to use a private npm repo, ugh) of this approach, you can simply use the webfonts&css flavor and your problem will be solved without changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `key={Math.random()}`  I'm using the `PRIMARY KEY` from the record