# ReactJs Exception in production, unable to reproduce, looking for help to reproduce it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following picture you can see a exception from my production loggserver. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is, nor can I reproduce the problem in any browser.

> [image: Exception from react error boundary]
>
> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

I'm looking for a good way to reproduce an error like this.. I do not run any jquery or anything that would modify the dom.. I use semantic-ui-react (according them they do not run jquery either)

I guess some user could use Google-translate or something that would modify the dom and cause a crash of react, but seems farfetched.

I also do not swallow exceptions in my api-calls (which seems to be a common thing that people warn about when searching for this on google.)

I run React 16.8.4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Something is probably manipulating the DOM outside React, but it's hard to tell what exactly without more information about the packages involved. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358529/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-with-fontawesome-in-react).

Comment: Yes that is why I mentioned semantic-ui-react, since it uses font-awsome under the hood. But the thing is, this error just happens randomly for users. It would be great if react could print some info of what it is trying to remove. I looked for this error on the semantic-ui-react github/issues page but found nothing.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger this error by deleting stuff from the dom manually (chrome-devtools) ? I have tried but cannot even make it crash that way..

Comment: Hmm, I was able to reproduce it now by editing a modal from a div to a span in devtools and the unmounting it ..

Comment: I was not logging the componentStack from my ErrorBoundary, that should help me isolate the error better.

Comment: If it happens to some users randomly, it might be caused even by a browser extension like AdBlock

Comment: Yes, it could be that

Comment: I had the same problem here. Did you manage to work this out?

Comment: This is not really fixable as you cannot control what extensions a random user is using. Extensions can alter the dom tree which makes react mad.