# react data table column filter problem with sort

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using react data table for my project. currently I am using column filtering feature and column sort feature. This is my table header.

```
 <thead>
  {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
      {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
        <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
          {column.render("Header")}
          <span>
            {column.isSorted ? (
              column.isSortedDesc ? (
                <i class="mdi mdi-menu-down sort-arrow"></i>
              ) : (
                <i class="mdi mdi-menu-up sort-arrow"></i>
              )
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </span>
          <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}</div>
        </th>
      ))}
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  ))}
</thead>
```

Column filter and Column sort features are working correctly. but my problem is, when I click column filter textbox, column sort start to fire and sorting header. Reason is all element is inside the same'th'. how I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this

```
<th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
          {column.render("Header")}
          <span>
            {column.isSorted ? (
              column.isSortedDesc ? (
                <i class="mdi mdi-menu-down sort-arrow"></i>
              ) : (
                <i class="mdi mdi-menu-up sort-arrow"></i>
              )
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </span>
          <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}</div>
        </th>
```

to

```
<th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
<span  {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
          {column.render("Header")}
          <span>
            {column.isSorted ? (
              column.isSortedDesc ? (
                <i class="mdi mdi-menu-down sort-arrow"></i>
              ) : (
                <i class="mdi mdi-menu-up sort-arrow"></i>
              )
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </span>
</span>
          <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}</div>
        </th>
```

should solve the issue, basically `getSortByToggleProps` return sort related props, so you need to provide them to that element only on click of which you want to sort

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps because OP doesn't seem to be using FontAwesome, but I came here with a similar problem and found this solution: [Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' with FontAwesome in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358529/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-with-fontawesome-in-react)